# undefined method `key?' for "/login" on RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm setting up a reservation engine in rails, I'll explain how the login process is, the login is with devise, all of that is ok, but each user (company) when logging in, should register the person who I am manipulating the system, there I have a problem, since there I must do a login and give permission to enter the system, I decided to do it like this:

from the root I redirect it to a loginuser view that is in the page controller, the loginuser method is inside devise there you will see it, and in this loginuser view I put together a partial where I make a form and there it gives me this error

undefined method `key?' for "/login"

The question is what it means and how to fix it.
I'll tell you the code

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [ :home ]
  before_action :authenticate_user!, only:[ :loginuser ]

  def new
    
    @contact = Contact.new
    @client = Cliente.new
  end

  def home
    if current_user == NIL

    else
      @client = Client.find_by(user_id: current_user.id)
      @contact = Contact.find_by(client_id: @client.id)
      redirect_to loginuser_path
    end
    
  end

  def loginuser
    @client = Client.find_by(user_id: current_user.id)
    @contact = Contact.find_by(client_id: @client.id)
  end
  
end
```

this code controller page

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 text-center">
      <%= image_tag "Motorhotel.png", class: "Logo img-fluid", alt: 'Logo_App' %>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
    <br>
      <h2 class="pb-4 text"><%= "Ingresar" %></h2>
      <%= simple_form_for @contact, html: loginuser_path do |f| %>
      <%= f.input :mail, label: "Correo Electronico" %>
      <%= f.input :pass, label: "Contraseña" %>
      <%= f.submit "Agregar"%>
      <% end %>
    </div> 
  </div>
</div>
```

This is partial view

Comment: There's no call to `key?` in the code. Could you show the line (and surrounding lines) the error comes from? You're probably passing in a String to something that expects a [Hash](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Hash.html#method-i-key-3F).

Comment: Copy/paste the actual error you're getting showing the stack trace.

Comment: Trace of template inclusion: #<ActionView::Template app/views/contacts/loginuser.html.erb locals=[]>

Comment: Showing /Users/juanpablogroverpinto/code/mounkey/ReserveEngenibeGO_Hotel/app/views/shared/home/_homewithuser.html.erb where line #9 raised:

Comment: i change html  to url  in line 9 or <%= simple_form_for @contact, html: loginuser_path do |f| %>and change the problems, if it changes the word change the problem to  undefined method `model_name' for nil:NilClass i don't know thank for your answer

Answer (score 0):

The solution is replace in lien 9 or <%= simple_form_for @contact, html: loginuser_path do |f| %> for <%= simple_form_for @contact, url: loginuser_path do |f| %>

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 text-center">
      <%= image_tag "Motorhotel.png", class: "Logo img-fluid", alt: 'Logo_App' %>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
    <br>
      <h2 class="pb-4 text"><%= "Ingresar" %></h2>
      <%= simple_form_for @contact, html: loginuser_path do |f| %>
      <%= f.input :mail, label: "Correo Electronico" %>
      <%= f.input :pass, label: "Contraseña" %>
      <%= f.submit "Agregar"%>
      <% end %>
    </div> 
  </div>
</div>
```